Doordarshan telefilm, A Love story but girl turns into nun
I saw this made for TV movie back in 90's on Hindi Indian television channel Doordarshan. 
The boy and Girl fall in Love with each other. Boy teases girl and ran away. The girl follows him and they both fall.
Boy has to go for some job/war. On hearing the news that boy has died girl becomes a nun.
Last scene: Boy is back and is sad to see that they cannot be together anymore.
I just remember glimpses as I was a kid back then. Have been searching for this like ever.
The TV I watched it on was a black & white one. So, I am not sure if it was a color movie or not. But in my opinion it has to be a color one as I saw it after movies like Jadui Coat came into existence.
